# gnuplot: legend gets hidden behind data

Tags: gnuplot, legend

I am new to gnuplot and while plotting stacked histogram, I find that legend gets hidden behind the data.

Is there a method to put the legend above the data? Thanks a lot for your help.
EDIT: I am currently using set key outside bottom to place legend outside, but that is not the best solution I would like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recent versions allow to make the background of the legend white:

```
set key opaque
```

This simply adds a white background to the legend so it appears on top of all graphs. Found the answer in [this Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9803163/bring-legend-to-the-front-in-gnuplot).

Answer (score 3):

If you would rather have the key on top of the data rather than the key outside the plot box altogether, here is one workaround (using sin(10*x) as an example):

```
set multiplot
unset key
plot sin(10*x) # this will plot with tics and a border, but no key
set key box
unset tics
unset border
bignumber=10 # make this number larger than the y range so the line will not be seen
plot [][0:1] bignumber title 'sin(10*x)' # this will just plot the key with the title
unset multiplot
```

Using this method, first you plot your data/function, then you create a plot on top of that which just has a key.  You have to make sure to set the title of the second plot properly.

Comment: Thanks for that solution, but isn't it more of a workaround? Gnuplot somehow must allow to draw the legend on top of all data without the multiplot trick, right? I think it's not a seldom case or special feature, ... still searching for something better ...

Comment: Older and wiser now, I have learned of the `set key opaque` command which draws the key after all data have been plotted!