# How to put a rectangle in the key with same hue as a shaded area in Gnuplot?

Tags: object, gnuplot, shading

I have some shaded area in a plot and I'd like to label that shaded area with a small rectangle of the same hue as the shading in the plot.

I'm using gnuplot - my shading in the plot is achieved with

```
plot  'XXXX.dat' u 1:($2+$3):($2-$3) w filledcurve ls 999 fs solid 0.2 notitle,\
```

and I'd like to label the shading area in the key with a small rectangle of the same hue.

Is it possible? I'm also happy to set it manually via

```
set object rectangle from x1,y1 to x2,y2 fc rgb "blue"
```

but in this way I've only managed to sample colours from the standard gnu plot palette and not the hue I've set for the shading via `fs solid 0.2`.

Thanks!

Comment: Is your question sufficiently answered?

Comment: @theozh yes sorry I had forgotten to accept your answer, thanks again indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your problem.
If you want the filled area in your key you have to define a keyentry via `title` but you are using `notitle`.

**Code:**

```
set key out
plot '+' u 1:($1**2) w filledcurves ls 999 fs solid 0.2 title "filled area"
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If theozh's answer does not apply, e.g. if you want a key entry with a color that is not the entire plot, then current gnuplot (version 5.2.6 or newer) offers a special plot component `keyentry` that produces a title and sample for any plot style without actually plotting anything.  Example:

```
set key title "Key made with explicit \n{/:Italic keyentry} elements"
plot keyentry with points pt '¶' title "points", \
     keyentry with lp title "lp", \
     keyentry with yerrorbars title "yerrorbars", \
     keyentry with xyerrorlines title "xyerrorlines", \
     keyentry with circles fs solid fc "dark-red" title "circles", \
     keyentry with ellipses title "ellipses", \
sin(x)/x lc "grey" dt '.-' lw 3 title "normal plot", \
     keyentry with boxerrorbars title "boxerrorbars", \
     keyentry with boxplot fs pattern 1 title "boxplot", \
     keyentry with labels point pt 4 title "labels", \
     keyentry with vectors title "vectors"
```

[image]